# What does the color behind the question mean?

Tags: support, questions

I've seen some questions on the Stack Overflow front page having orange colored background. What is the meaning of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often times the colors are used to highlight things like tags you've marked as a favorite or a post that belongs to you.

Answer (score 3):

[Did you see this post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)